# What could cause realtime lighting within a viewport to be calculated on the wrong part of the screen?

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadow

(I initially posted this in a section that is less suited for the particular issue, oops)

I'm having this issue on some of my client's computers (this is for a Unity asset) that I cannot reproduce on my machine, so finding a fix is incredibly difficult. I'm using camera.rect to render to only part of a screenspace rendertexture to save on render time. For those of you unfamiliar with Unity, as far as I can tell it's analogous to glviewport.

The issue is, on some older mac computers, realtime lighting is totally shot. The lighting appears to render only within a rectangle that is of the same SIZE as the correct one, but that is docked at 0,0. Additionally, it's not like the lighting data is just slid over, since even though the lighting is only rendering for part of the screen it's not computing it incorrectly in that portion.

This happens in both forward and deferred rendering, and does not happen with baked lights. It is only reproducible on older mac machines, which I do not have access to. What on earth could cause this?

[image: Issue visualization]

EDIT:

Well, that's not good. It looks like this issue is present in Unity version 5.6 as well, even on my windows 10 machine with a GTX 1080. I cannot for the life of me figure out what could cause this, but I'll be inspecting it with renderdoc to see what I can find.
[image: 5.6 bug]